# Square root of non-negative number

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

How can one be sure that for every real number $x\in\mathbb R$ with $x\geq0$ there is a unique number $a\geq 0$ such that $a^2 = x$?

Comment: Btw, you can use the notation $x\in\mathbb R^+$.  And there isn't a unique $a$, since $-a$ also satisfies that.  Perhaps require $a>0$.

Comment: Thanks; I edited the answer such that $a\geq 0$

Comment: Realize this is more or less a question of bijection, which can be answered with monotonacity.

Comment: we need to know more about your background to give a tailored answer to you. What do you know about real numbers ?

Comment: I think you can prove by contradiction. So suppose $a^2 = x = b^2$ where $a \ne b$. We can assume $a > b$. With simple reasoning you can show that $a<b$, a contradiction.

Comment: There's a very slick proof in the first few pages of Baby Rudin, using only the least upper bound property, that every non-negative real has an $n$th root for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

The "axiom of completeness" distinguishes the reals from the rationals  (where this statement is not true, e.g. $\sqrt 2$). It says every set of real numbers with an upper bound has a least upper bound.

If $x > 1$ then clearly $\sqrt x \lt x$, while if $x \le 1$ then $\sqrt x \le 1$.

So the set of all numbers $a$ such that $a^2 < x $ is bounded above and therefore has a least upper bound. One can then show that the LUB is in fact the square root.

(as a point of interest this is normally ignored in the usual proof that $\sqrt 2$ is an irrational number. The proof normally given uses contradiction to show that $(p/q)^2 $ cannot equal $2$ for any integer $p, q$  but fails to show that it is a real number).

Answer (score 1):

If we prove $x=a^2$ is bijective for $a\ge0$, we prove that it is one-to-one, which establishes that $a$ is unique for each $x$.  Since we have $x'=2a\ge0$ for all $a\ge0$, we know that this is monotone.  Since $x=a^2$ is continuous, it is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Using the intermediate value theorem for $f(a)=a^2-x$ one finds that $f(0)=-x<0$ and $f(1+\frac{x}2)=1+\frac{x^2}4>0$ so that $f$ has at least one root inside that interval. Strict monotonicity, $0<a<b\implies f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)(b+a)>0$, guarantees that there is exactly one root.